# How to add existing elements to a new XML object with PrependChild in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file with a basic structure like this:

```
<list>
    <section>
         <rule>
              <name>blah</name>
              <sources>
                   <source>
                        <name>blahsource</name>
                   </source>
              </sources>
        </rule>
    </section>
</list>
```

I'm importing the file as an XMl object to Powershell like this:

```
$firewallSections = [xml] (Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\ExportedRules.xml")
```

Then I loop through to make modifications to the  entries like this:

```
foreach ($section in $firewallSections.list.section)
{
    DoesSomeThingHere()
}
```

What I need to do is add each $section to a new XML object in reverse order using PrependChild. Ideally something like this:

```
$reversed.PrependChild($section)
```

So then I could loop through like:

```
foreach($section in $reversed.section)
```

I'm just not able to figure out how to do this. I have been getting errors like:

```
Exception calling "PrependChild" with "1" argument(s): "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$reversed.PrependChild($reversed.OwnerDocument.ImportNode($section, 1))`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting this error when using that line:

    `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    +         $reversed.PrependChild($reversed.OwnerDocument.ImportNode($se ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: This seems to work:

`$reversed.DocumentElement.PrependChild($reversed.ImportNode($section, 1))`

Note I just added the DocumentElement to your line. I will test and see if it delivers the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working how I wanted. First I had to define the variable like this:

```
$reversed = [XML] "<list></list>"
```

Then I added this line inside my foreach loop:

```
$reversed.DocumentElement.PrependChild($reversed.ImportNode($section, 1))  | out-null
```

Thanks for the help!